# Different formats (bit rate) of audio data for entering Automatic speech recognition models

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm, speech-recognition, audio-processing

I'm wondering what should I do before any preprocessing for audio data with different formats

for example, assume you have telephony data with 8kbit/s and also mp3 data with 250kbit/s
What is the best way to integrate these two types of formats?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure your ASR model is robust to different audio coding formats, bitrates and other channel noise. If that is the case, you can just load your audio files, resample to a standard sample-rate, and input to the model.